# Yii2 backend bootstrap treeview url is not working properly

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I integrated AdminLTE with Yii2 framework, created the model and generated the CRUD models without any issues. But when I try the treeview URL to access the page, it's showing a *page not found* error and I don't know how to fix this issue.

Could you please tell me what's wrong with my code ?

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">
    <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>
    <li>
        <a href="index.php">
            <i class="fa fa-dashboard"/>
            <span>Dashboard</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="treeview">
        <a href="#">
           <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
           <span>User</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="index.php?r=users/create">
                    <i class="fa fa-user-circle"/>Create User
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="index.php?r=users">
                    <i class="fa fa fa-eye"/>View User
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And I attached the Image error message screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be a singular/plural problem in your link? Is your controller class named `UserController` or `User`s`Controller`?

If you're following the [Yii schema design guidelines](http://%20%20https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/227/guidelines-for-good-schema-design#do-name-your-database-tables-in-the-singular-not-plural), your users model / controller should be named `User`. So your link should be `<a href="index.php?r=user/create">` and 
`<a href="index.php?r=user">`

You should also consider to write your links using Yii's helpers [Url::to](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/helper-url) that take care of every aspect of your application's configuration:

`<?= Url::to(['user/index']) ?>`